# Using "ponder" as an intransitive verb?

Tags: difference, verbs, phrasal-verbs, objects, understanding

In one my novels, a separate section is given as **Points to Ponder Over.** However, no phrasal verb as such (ponder over) really exists. By Oxford dictionary, **ponder** is a transitive verb. So it cannot be used without as object, so just to have an object, an **over**(a preposition) has been added?

In oxford dictionary, an example is given as

> She sat pondering over her problem.

[Source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ponder)

But I wonder, why not use just **ponder** when no such phrasal verb **ponder over** really exists.

Also sometimes phrasal verbs and verbs have the same meaning, eg- **follow and follow up, add and add up**,etc. In that case, which should I prefer to speak/write?

Comment: "Ponder" can be transitive and intransitive. You yourself gave an example of its intransitive use in "She sat pondering over her problem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**[Ponder](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ponder)**" is both intransitive and transitive. This verb means "***to think carefully about something, especially for a noticeable length of time***"

1. She *ponders* the reaction she’ll receive. (***Transitive***)
2. The back porch is a quiet place where I can *ponder*. (***Intransitive***)

In US the verb **ponder** as a *transitive verb* is followed by a direct object mostly *without any preposition* alongside:

- They *pondered* their chances of success.
- We *pondered* the events of the day.
- He *pondered* the question before he answered.

In both US and UK it can be followed by such prepositions as "**on**", "**over**" *(being the most common one)*, and "**upon**" *(being the least common one, dated or formal)*

Comment: Why should it require any preposition? Why it cannot stand alone as you have done in your second example? What difference would it make if I say "points to ponder" and "points to ponder over"?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh Both are acceptable. It's your choice whether to include a preposition or not